# Supporting Theory for P-Names in Forcing?

Tags: set-theory

In Kunen 10th Edition 2006, it is stated on p188 that the concept of P-name is used to generate "all the sets which can be constructed from G by applying set-theoretic processes definable in M". The construction in Definition 2.5 : $\tau$ is a P-Name (based upon the partial order P) iff

(i) $\tau$ is a relation

(ii) $\forall$ <$\sigma$,p> $\in$ $\tau$ [$\sigma$ is a P-Name $\wedge$ p $\in$ P]

This 'looks' like a straightforwards definition but on some thought it has hidden depths and as a newbie to the subject I will be grateful if anyone knows of any references that fully explain in mathematical detail that is going on e.g. to answer the following types of questions:

q1) P-Names look to be a sort of coding of set theory expressions that can represent objects in Models (e.g. for expressions such as A $ \cap$ B), but the definition includes no direct mention of the set theory expressions that create the P-Name objects they represent.

q2) How do the P-Names have the remarkable property that they definitely represent in M all possible objects in the new model with G added (M[G])? I was looking for some definition of equivalence classes and homomorphisms to prove that a selected set S of P-Names has the property that

- each P-Name in S can represent an object in M[G] via VAL whatever G is selected and
- that the set of P-Names in S is enough to represent all sets in M[G].

So even though a specific P-Name could evaluate (via VAL) to a different set in M[G] for different G, when all P-names in S are taken into account the full set of elements in M[G] is produced.

q3) If P-Names are coding via some algorithm 'possible' elements of all possible G$_i $, and assuming that $\cup$G$_i $ = P, presumably <$\sigma$,p> means roughly in logical terms "IF p $\in$ G THEN $\sigma$ results" and "if p $\notin$ G then $\sigma$ is ignored". However e.g. the object {1} $\cap$ G in M[G] is produced via a P-Name expression in M of {<$\hat{1}$,p>:p $\in$P} $\cap$ {<$\hat{p}$,p>:p$\in$P} = {<$\hat{1}$,1>} using the standard "$\in$" operation which $\mathbf{remarkably}$ for some reason now isn't concerned whether < A,p> expressions mean "IF  ... THEN" but instead "$\in$" treats all the < A,p> expressions as 'definite' and not 'possible' existing objects (a case of a 'definite maybe' !?)

q4) The P-Names only seem to code the property of G $\subset$ P, but none of the other properties such as being a filter or intersecting dense sets, so presumably there is some reason for this?

Comment: Why should the definition of $P$-names mention anything about set theoretic expressions? It's a definition, that's all. It turns out that it is a very useful and good definition.

Comment: By definition (at least by Kunen's) $M[G]$ is the set of names evaluated by $G$. It turns out that this is the smallest transitive model extending $M$, containing $G$ and satisfying $ZFC$.

Comment: The mechanism being exploited is akin to the idea here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine#Definitions ; In general, the domain-side of a name represents individual cells of a kind of "work-tape" while the range-side represents cells of an "oracle-tape".

Comment: The thing that makes this entire process interesting is a cute back-and-fourth that happens between elements of  $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathbb{P}$-names relatively definable from them.

Comment: @NotMike - very neat idea indeed. I was wondering if you know of any references that describe this process you describe further ?

Comment: The discussion surrounding Lemma IV.2.25 (p. 252) of the 2013 edition of Kunen's text does a nice job of outlining the process. The idea is that the forcing relation can be used as a "guide" in the construction of a $\mathbb{P}$-name for a particular object you need to prove exists in the extension. Roughly speaking, given any $\mathbb{P}$-name, the statements forced by some $p$ to hold about it's evaluation are witnessed by dense subsets of conditions below $p$; the cool bit is that this also works in the opposite direction namely from dense sets you can witness new $\mathbb{P}$-names.

Comment: @NotMike - thanks I have just found your kind reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand question 1 - what exactly do you not see that you think you should?

---

Your question 2 makes it sound like $M[G]$ comes *first* and names are defined *later*. But that's the wrong way around: by definition, $M[G]$ is the set of the valuations of the names, so there's nothing to explain here - of course everything in $M[G]$ is named by some name in $M$ via $G$, since that's exactly how $M[G]$ is defined.

---

The beginning of question 3 is basically right: you can think of a name as an "If-then-else" description (appropriately iterated of course). But you seem to be conflating names and the things they name: while the thing *described by* a name is "contingent" on the generic, the *name itself* isn't. Remember that names are themselves elements of $M$. The name for $\{1\}\cap G$ you describe, for example, is a perfectly nice element of $M$, and so forth. Put another way: **names are definite objects**.

However - and I think this will clarify things - the *manner in which* these definite objects relate via $G$ to their referents is complicated: **basic operations on names don't always correspond to those same operations on the valuations**. For example, the intersection of two names is **not** in general a name for their intersection: it will always be a name for *subset* of their intersection, but it might "undershoot." For example, fix some maximal antichain $A$ in $\mathbb{P}$ not containing $1$, and consider $\mu=\{\langle \emptyset, 1\rangle\}$ and $\nu=\{\langle \emptyset, p\rangle: p\in A\}$; for any $G$ we have $\mu[G]=\nu[G]=\{\emptyset\}$, but $(\mu\cap\nu)[G]=\emptyset$.

---

Re: your fourth question, your observation is correct: names do **not** in fact take into account that $G$ is a generic filter. However, their **analysis** does. Suppose $X$ is any subset of $\mathbb{P}$ (probably outside $M$). We can recursively define $\nu[X]$ for $\nu$ a $\mathbb{P}$-name in $M$ as usual, and we can consider the structure consisting of all those valuations. However, *this structure has no reason to be a model of ZFC a priori* (or have any of the other nice properties we want).

So really you should think of this as a two-part idea: first the idea of "conditional sets" via names, and second the realization that generic filters in particular make names behave really well. This second observation doesn't come out of nowhere, but while learning this material I think it's important to keep the observations separate.

(Incidentally, the hitting-dense-sets aspect of the generic filter definition should be the only surprising bit. The general intuitive picture is this: we want conditions to describe facts about an imagined object we're building, and we want $G$ to be the set of all the true facts about that object (really $G$ **is** that object, but meh). If something is true then everything it implies is also true, and this is why $G$ needs to be closed upwards; and no two contradictory things can be simultaneously true, which is why $G$ doesn't contain any two incompatible conditions. **The realization, against this backdrop, of how dense sets help shape things is the key to really understanding forcing.**)

Comment: Very nice indeed on your last paragraph! q1)  was really asking about any Model Theoretic references that shows the link from the elements in M to the set of P-Names to the model M[G] they are are intended to describe. So there would be the usual ∈ used for the set of P-Names and a different ∈' in M[G] e.g. in M[G] a ∈' b  <-> ∃p∈G (<a,p> ∈ b) , representing the VAL operation. The existing sets in M could be mapped to a subset of the P-Names (i.e. x ∈  M maps to x' := {<y',p> : y ∈ x and p ∈ P}. I thought the set of P-Names could be viewed as some sort of  model as well ?

Comment: so I was assuming that M --> P-Names --> M[G] is like the extension Field method in Algebra (e.g. Allenby, Rings Fields & Groups- 2003 edition, page 148 where the transform is F --> S --> S bar).

Comment: or probably a closer correspondence to extension field method would be M --> P-Names --> P-Names in equivalence classes to cater for multiple subsets G of P --> M[G]  equivalent to F --> F[x] --> S --> S bar.

Comment: On q2) Cohens book "Set Theory and the Continuum hypothesis" and there the 'labelling' method presented does look to be producing a set of true 'labels' - i.e. 'labels' for elements in the final model M[G] which are considered true for all G, and then the final model is VAL(all 'labels' considered true for all G). Maybe this isn't being done with P-Names?